# Cmake file cannot connect directories error

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a CMakefile and I am having trouble fixing my errors. I am not sure if I am typing up something right or not.

```
user/a/anbaraja/Homework3/util/Kepler.cxx:1:21: fatal error:  Planet1.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Planet1.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/runKepler.dir/util/Kepler.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runKepler.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have a previous question where it breaks down my files and where they are stored called

Multiple definition of classes error for seperated files

If you look that up in stack flow.

```
# Project name
project(Kepler)

# Declaring external packages


# Create the libraries : Planet1 Planet2
add_library(Planet1 SHARED ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Planet1.cxx ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Planet1.h)
add_library(Planet2 SHARED ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Planet2.cxx ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Planet2.h)
# They create commands like g++ -c -o .cxx ....

# Create the executable
add_executable(runKepler ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/util/Kepler.cxx)


#Link include directories with libraries
target_include_directories( Planet1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories( Planet2 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

Comment: Where is `Planet1.h`?

Comment: I think you did not link to your 2 libraries. If you don't link to them then the `runKepler` target does not use the public include directories since without linking it does not depend on either of the library targets. I believe you need a `target_link_libraries(runKepler  PRIVATE Planet1 Planet2)`

Comment: @Devolus It is in the directory called include

Comment: @drescherjm I tried it out and it did not work

Comment: That may have to be after the target_include_directories() and you will have to regenerate with cmake and make clean.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah I still get same error I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You should add your include directory to your search path:

For example:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/includes) 
include_directories(/my/includes) 
...
```

Comment: It did not work. I know for make files I have to make clean and then run it as make. Do I have to do the same for CMake files ?

Comment: Obviously you must use your path. I just wrote an example.